# EntityMetadataWrapperException when updating Open Atrium

Tags: entities, updating

I've taken over management of a site using Open Atrium on the [Pantheon](https://pantheon.io/) hosting platform. The upstream repository was originally set incorrectly to Drupal 7 instead of Open Atrium. What this means is that if I want to be able to push any Open Atrium updates, I need to migrate the current site over to a fresh Open Atrium install.

I have a local install using the latest version of [Open Atrium for Pantheon](https://github.com/phase2/openatrium-drops-7). I've been trying to import my current production database, then run update.php, following Open Atrium best practices for updates (including `drush registry-rebuild`). I keep getting the following exception thrown:

`EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property bootstrap_tour_step_reference. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (line 335 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/profiles/openatrium/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).`

I've found references to this error and Organic Groups ([here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1519884) and [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1467820)), and looked into [Open Atrium issues](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/openatrium?text=EntityMetadataWrapperException&status=All&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=All) containing this exception message, but nothing seems relevant.

Do I need to look into manually running `hook_schema`, or `hook_schema_alter` on the current production site before importing that database into the fresh Open Atrium install?

Edit: After learning a bit more about `drush rr`, it looks like the registry-rebuild isn't completing. Any tips for trouble-shooting registry-rebuild fails? Seems like registry-rebuild itself is kind of a last-ditch method, so I'm at a loss!